# Android XML Styling

Tags: xml, android, styling

I'm using themes to style widgets in Android.

With the code:

```
<item name="android:width">200px</item>
```

... i can set the width of the widget to 200px.

But how can I specify "wrap_content" and "fill_parent"?

Strings are not allowed there!

Answer (score 2):

`wrap_content` and `fill_parent` are valid for `layout_height` and `layout_width` not width.